# Introspect parameter of type: id to decide whether it is a class or a protocol

Tags: objective-c, protocols, introspection

I have the following method:

```
-(void)SomeMethod:(id)classOrProtocol;
```

It will be called like this:

```
[self someMethod:@protocol(SomeProtocol)];
```

Or

```
[self someMethod:[SomeClass class]];
```

Within the method body I need to decide if |classOrProtocol| is:

Any Class(Class) OR Any Protocol(Protocol) OR Anything else

```
[[classOrProtocol class] isKindOfClass: [Protocol class]]
```

Results in a (build)error:

> Receiver 'Protocol' is  a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist

So how can I tell a Protocol from a Class from anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C 2 (i.e. unless you use 32 bit runtime on OS X) `Protocol` is defined to be just a forward class, see `/usr/include/objc/runtime.h`. The real interface is nowhere declared. You can try to include `/usr/inlcude/objc/Protocol.h` by saying

```
#import <objc/Protocol.h>
```

but as is written there, no method is publicly supported for an instance of `Protocol`. The only accepted way to deal with `Protocol` instances is to use runtime functions, given in [Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html). It's not even publicly defined whether `Protocol` is a subclass of anything, and it's not even stated that it implements `NSObject` protocol. So you can't call any method on it.

Of course you can use the source code of the runtime to see what's going on.  `Protocol` inherits from `Object` (which is a remnant from pre-OpenStep NeXTSTep), not from `NSObject`. So you can't use the familiar methods for `NSObject`-derived objects, including `Class` of `NSObject`-derived objects. See the opensourced implementations of [Protocol.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/Protocol.h) and [Protocol.m](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/Protocol.m). As you see there,  the class `Protocol` itself doesn't do anything, because every method just casts `self` to `protocol_t` and calls a function. In fact, as can be seen from the function `_read_images` and others in [`objc-runtime-new.mm`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm), the `isa` pointer of a `Protocol` object is set *by hand* when the executable and libraries are loaded, and never used.

So, don't try to inspect whether an `id` is a `Protocol` or not.

If you really need to do this, you can use

```
id foo=...;
if(foo->isa==class_getClass("Protocol")){
    ...
}
```

But, seriously, don't do it.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I am using this method in code related to dependency injection, and in this context I think it makes sense. But perhaps I should split it into two methods.

Comment: Added a bit more info on the internal. It was fun reading the source code, thanks for the nice question, 1ndivisible!

Answer (score -1):

This is not an issue 'caused by inability to determine whether it's class or protocol. The error is 'caused by missing interface of `Protocol` class. Make sure you import `Protocol.m` at the top of your implementation file where you're testing argument's type.

You can also try using `NSClassFromString()` function which will return `Class` object or `nil`. Do note though that if `nil` is returned it doesn't mean that argument is protocol. It just means that it could be undefined class too!

There is also method `NSProtocolFromString` which returns appropriate results - Protocol for protocol and `nil` for undefined protocol.

Comment: Thanks for replying. If I try and import "Protocol.m" (Or "Protocol.h") I get a "File Not Found" Error. I am also able to use Protocol as a parameter type in the same file without any import.

Comment: Right, I figured it's a bit of a nonsense, since Protocol is a class for actual protocol type which doesn't have Protocol.(h|m) files as such. Sorry to misguide you.